# Update Python for Visual Studio 2017 Professional

Tags: python, visual-studio-2017

Can anyone point me in the right direction to update the version of Python that is installed with Visual Studio 2017 Professional. All the guidance out there is on how to install it, but not update once it is on.

The reason I need to do this is that the version installed is being flagged as having vulnerabilities. Current version is 3.6.6 and it needs to be on 3.7.11

I have updated Visual Studio, but it has not updated this component/tool.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Quick comment, I just noticed that there is an option within tools for Extensions and Updates but I don't see the required update in there.

Comment: IN a similar positionm wrt VS 2017 Community. 3.6.6 is out of support, the installation in VS shared is gone (who deleted it? Me or MS?) and I can find no way to add a later version... or to find out if any later version is in fact support. V. frustrating that there is no info on this in the app or from MS -- or if there is, it is deeply buried.